# Protected by legislation

Tags: meaning, grammar

Recently a friend of mine had to take a workplace safety quiz, and one of the questions asked:

"Discrimination is a form of workplace bullying protected by legislation. True or false?"

The answer was 'true'. I live in a fairly progressive country, so I can only assume that the sentence is not meant to be read literally, since there probably aren't laws intended to protect people who discriminate in the workplace. How should sentences like this be interpreted, and why on earth is it written this way?

Comment: Are you sure it didn't say _prohibited_?  Either the answer was incorrect or the question was.  (Unless, of course, discrimination _is_ protected by law in your country.  The way things are here in the US, that's quickly becoming true.)

Comment: I'm not sure of the background behind "protected by legislation," but the phrase means that discriminatory acts are regulated by the federal government. @RogerSinasohn Protected, as weird as it may seem, is commonly use and was probably used in the question asker's sentence.

Comment: Ah, those wacky lawyers!  What hijinks will they get into next?  8^)  I stand corrected and I've learned something new.

Comment: It's just another idiotically written sentence. Voting to close.

Comment: I hope it is not too late to point out that the workplace, and indeed the whole world, is full of discrimination that is not bullying, is not illegal, and ought to be encouraged. Examples: we want the airline we fly with to discriminate between competent pilots and incompetent pilots; we want our butcher to discriminate between meat that is good to eat and meat that is not fit for human consumption; we want our schools to discriminate  between competent and incompetent teachers of our children. It is discrimination on irrelevant criteria that is the problem.